# Akka stream sort by id in java

Tags: java, sorting, functional-programming, akka, akka-stream

I need to sort my akka stream list by id in java
I have list of objects in akka source:

```
SystemCodeTracking{id=9, EntityName='table3'}
SystemCodeTracking{id=2, EntityName='table2'}
SystemCodeTracking{id=10, EntityName='table1'}
```

I need to sort it to:

```
SystemCodeTracking{id=2, EntityName='table2'}
SystemCodeTracking{id=9, EntityName='table3'}
SystemCodeTracking{id=10, EntityName='table1'}
```

Code should be like following:

```
Source<SystemCodeTracking, SourceQueueWithComplete<SystemCodeTracking>> loggedSource = source.map(single -> sortingFunction(single));
```

My question is how to do the `sortingFunction` ?

Comment: Sorting function must have two arguments - two elements to be compared

Answer (score 4):

A stream is by definition unbounded => providing a perfect ordering requires to have observed *all* the data before emitting the first one.

However, there are tons of situations though where it can be assumed that a stream is just *partially* unsorted, that is, data gets slightly mixed up due to concurrent processing, though each element would end up being no further than, say, 1000 positions from its real position.

When that is the case, you can use a sort method with a buffer, like so:

```
   * partial sort of a stream: wait for <bufferSize> to be buffered, the start flushing them out in order
   * */
  def sort[T, S](bufferSize: Int, order: T => S)(implicit ordering: Ordering[S]): () => T => Iterable[T] = () => {

    var buffer = List.empty[T]

    t: T => {
      buffer = (buffer :+ t).sortBy(order)
      if (buffer.size < bufferSize) Iterable.empty[T]
      else {
        val r = buffer.head
        buffer = buffer.tail
        List(r)
      }
    }
  }
```

which can simply be used as part of a `statefulMapConcat`, as follows:

```
someSource
// sort the stream by timestpam, using a buffer of 1000, 
.statefulMapConcat(sort(1000, _.timestamp))
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorting basically kills the nature of your stream, as you'll need to consume the whole stream - i.e. fitting it into memory - to apply a sorting function. Anyway, it is possible by exhausting the whole source to a `Sink.seq`, and then sort the result.

```
source.runWith(Sink.seq, materializer)
```

and then on the completion stage result call

```
sortingFunction(result)
```

If you want to sort chunks of the source, and not the whole things, you can do something like

```
source.grouped(10).map(batch -> sortingFunction(batch))
```

Comment: I tried to do this Sink.seq().contramap(this::sortList).foreach(x -> System.out.println(x)); However it iseems my sortList function never called .  I had my source.toMat(sink. keep.left()).run(materializer)

Comment: you need to run the source against a sink.seq, and THEN sort the result. You cannot sort the result in a stream stage. you need to run the stream and sort the data afterwards

Comment: But Sink.seq() seems never run because streaming never finish. May sliding window could be a solution to group data together?

Comment: In general case, it's impossible to sort infinite stream. Just to figure out which element is to be first in the result stream, you have to compare it with all the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort a sequence (be it Akka Stream or anything else) if you can't find a minimum element of that sequence (which is to be emitted first in the resulting sorted stream). This is usually the case if the stream is infinite.

In some cases, you can sort even infinite stream, even within low memory limit - e. g. if you can determine next minimal element by looking at only N last elements. Or you can utilize the case-specific knowledge that, when *some_condition* is satisfied, you can be sure that *some_class* of elements will never occur in your stream.

Otherwise your only option is to escalate sorting problem one level up: do you really need strong order in your stream? Maybe it's enough to just partition the stream - i. e. split it into sub-streams of elements having the same key?

I guess the reason why Akka Streams has no `Flow.sort` out of the box is that Akka Streams are all about boundedness of resource consumption, and sorting streams requires O(n) of memory.